# How do I efficiently handle multiple inserts into an array?

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-2007, dynamic-arrays

I have a dynamically allocated array of integers into which I want to insert integers at arbitrary positions. Many integers as in  more than 2.5 million.

My code currently looks like this:

```
type
  TIntegerArr = array of Integer;

var
  FCount: Integer;
  FSortedList: TIntegerArr;

procedure Insert(_Value: Integer; _InsertPos: integer);
var
  OldList: TIntegerArr;
begin
  OldList := FSortedList;
  if Length(FSortedList) < FCount + 1 then begin
    OldList := FSortedList;
    FSortedList := nil;
    SetLength(FSortedList, FCount + 100);
    CopyMemory(@FSortedList[0], @OldList[0], SizeOf(Integer) * _InsertPos);
  end;
  MoveMemory(@FSortedList[_InsertPos + 1], @OldList[_InsertPos], SizeOf(Integer) * (FCount - _InsertPos));
  FSortedList[_InsertPos] := _Value;
  Inc(FCount);
end;
```

(The real code is a method of a class that has FSortedList and FCount as fields.)

Using a temporary list and using Move rather than a for loop for moving the data improved the performance already quite a lot because it prevents the array from being copied twice when it has to grow (once in SetLength on the existing array and another time with Move).

But the worst case Insert(SomeValue, 0) still always moves all existing values.

So far I was thinking along the lines of introducing an offset at the start of the array so rather than having to move all existing values every time a new value is inserted at the front, I could do that only when the offset reaches 0. E.g.:

```
// simple case: inserting at Position 0:
if FOffset = 0 then begin
  // [...] reallocate a new array as above
  Move(@FSortedList[100], @OldList, SizeOf(Integer) * _InsertPos);
  FOffset := 100;
end;
Dec(FOffset);
FSortedList[FOffset] := _NewValue;
```

(This code is untested and probably buggy)
This of course can be extended to check whether the insertion point is nearer to the beginning or the end and depending on that move either the first or the last values by one position so that on average only 1/4 of the entries has to be moved rather than 1/2 as it currently is.

Another option would be implementing a sparse array. I remember seeing such an implementation in some commercial library back in the 1990ies but don't remember which it was (TurboPower?).

This procedure is central to some sorting and indexing code which works on arrays of different sizes, from just a few dozen entries up to the above mentioned millions of entries.

Currently the program runs about 2 hours (before my optimizations it was close to 5 hours) and I already know that the number of entries in the array is going to at least double. As insert performance gets worse the larger the array already is, I suspect that with double the number of entries, the run time will at least quadruple.

I would like some suggestions on how to tune the performance. Memory consumption is currently not much of an issue but run time definitely is.

(This is Delphi 2007 but that should not make much of a difference unless newer Delphi versions already have an optimized library for doing the above. Classes.TList is not optimized.)

Edit1: Just found the sparse array implementation I mentioned above: It's StColl from TurboPower SysTools.

Edit2: Ok, some background: My program reads a DBase table with currently 2.4 million entries and generates several new tables from these entries. The new tables are normalized and are indexed after they have been created (For performance reasons I don't generate the indexes before inserting the data, trust me, I tried it first.). The array is the central piece of code that provides internal sorting for the generated tables. New records are only appended to the table, but their RecNo is inserted into the array in sorted order.

Comment: See [`Improved Sliced Array implementation`](http://www.cromis.net/blog/2013/03/improved-sliced-array-implementation/) by [`@Runner`](http://stackoverflow.com/users/118765/runner) if this gives any input how to make sorting better.

Comment: @LURD: Thanks. I read this blog post when he wrote it (the first comment on that page is mine) but had already forgotten.

Comment: Tell us more about use cases for this "insertable array". Possible solutions depend on them.

Comment: After your Edit2 I'm still unsure whether you really need an array, or another container would be a better choice...

Comment: You may try my [NLDSparseList](https://svn.apada.nl/svn/NLDelphi-opensource/ngln/NLDSparseList.pas).

Comment: @Mbo: A different container might be the better choice. Basically all I need is a data structure that let me store integers in an array like way, so I can use that structure as an index into another data structure that stores the actual data. But it must be update-able because my program inserts data all the time.

Comment: If you need a lot of inserts and you have a lot of data, you should consider using a linked list. Makes deleting fast too.

Comment: The Improved Sliced Array implementation blog post mentioned in the first comment is gone. It's on Archive.org though: https://web.archive.org/web/20170328165538/http://www.cromis.net/blog/2013/03/improved-sliced-array-implementation/

Answer (score 4):

Immediately after looking at your procedure I noticed some flaws. To see progress i first measured speed of your existing procedure in worst case scenario (adding number allways on the 0 position).

```
n:=500000;
for i:=0 to n-1
 do Insert(i, 0);
```

Measurement: n=500000 **47.6 ms**

**A) Simplicity**

I deleted some unnecessary lines from your procedure (OldList is totally unnecessary, SetLength preserves memory).

*Improvement A:*

```
procedure Insert(_Value: Integer; _InsertPos: integer);
begin
 if Length(FSortedList) < FCount + 1
    then SetLength(FSortedList, FCount + 100);
  Move(FSortedList[_InsertPos], FSortedList[_InsertPos+1], SizeOf(Integer) * (FCount - _InsertPos));
  FSortedList[_InsertPos] := _Value;
  Inc(FCount);
end;
```

Speed gain **6% (44.8 ms)**

**B) Everything counts**

```
if Length(FSortedList) < FCount + 1 
   then SetLength(FSortedList, FCount + 100);
```

- Tip 1: function Length is called on every insert
- Tip 2: FCount+1 is calculated every time
- Tip 3: procedure parameters as const (by reference)
- Tip 4: introduce FCapacity variable
- Tip 5: increasing length by just 100 will cause a lot of reallocations (25.000 on 2.5 million array). As you say, memory is not the problem, so why not just preallocate all or at least large?

*Improvement B:*

```
procedure Insert(const _Value, _InsertPos: integer);
begin
 if FCount = FCapacity
    then begin
     Inc(FCapacity, 100000);
     SetLength(FSortedList, FCapacity);
    end;
 Move(FSortedList[_InsertPos], FSortedList[_InsertPos+1], SizeOf(Integer) * (FCount - _InsertPos));
 FSortedList[_InsertPos] := _Value;
 Inc(FCount);
end;
```

Speed gain **1% (44.3 ms).**

*Hint: Instead of Inc by 100000 you can implement some progressive algorithm.*

**C) Bottleneck**

If we look at the procedure now, there is nothing left, just a lot of memory moves. If we can't change the algorithm, we must improve the memory move.

There was actually fastmove challenge (fastcode.sourceforge.net)

I prepared a zip, with just those files you need (3 files, source code). Link >>> http://www.dakte.org/_stackoverflow/files/delphi-fastcode.zip

- Add fastcodeCPUID.pas and fastmove.pas to your project!
- Insert Uses fastmove.pas;
- *Voila! Nothing else to change!*

**Speed gain on my machine almost 50%** (depends on CPU you are using).

**Original procedure**

```
n         ms graph
---------------------------------
100000   1.8 *
200000   7.6 ***
300000  17.0 *******
400000  30.1 *************
500000  47.6 ********************
```

**Improved, without fastmove (-7%)**

```
n         ms graph
---------------------------------
100000   1.6 *
200000   6.9 ***
300000  15.7 ******
400000  28.2 ***********
500000  44.3 ******************
```

**Improved, With fastmove (-46%)**

```
n         ms graph
---------------------------------
100000   0.8 *
200000   3.8 **
300000   9.0 ****
400000  16.3 *******
500000  25.7 ***********
```

*Last comments:*

```
 if FCount = FCapacity
    then begin
     if FCapacity<100000
        then FCapacity:=100000  
        else FCapacity:=FCapacity*2;
     SetLength(FSortedList, FCapacity);
    end;
```

As I said you can add some progressive FCapacity increase. This is some classical Grow implementation (just add more if's if needed or change 100000 to more apropriate value).

**D) Update 2: Array as ^TArray**

```
type
  PIntegerArr3 = ^TIntegerArr3y;
  TIntegerArr3y = array[0..1] of Integer;

var
 FCapacity3,
 FCount3: Integer;
 FSortedList3: PIntegerArr3;

procedure ResizeArr3(var aCurrentArr: PIntegerArr3; const aNewCapacity: Integer);
var lNewArr: PIntegerArr3;

begin
 GetMem(lNewArr, aNewCapacity*SizeOf(Integer));

 if FCount3>0 // copy data too
  then begin
    if aNewCapacity<FCount3
       then FCount3:=aNewCapacity; // shrink
    Move(aCurrentArr^[0], lNewArr^[0], FCount3*SizeOf(Integer));
  end;

 FreeMem(aCurrentArr, FCapacity3*SizeOf(Integer));
 FCapacity3:=aNewCapacity;
 aCurrentArr:=lNewArr;
end;

procedure FreeArr3;
begin
 if FCapacity3>0
  then begin
    FreeMem(FSortedList3, FCapacity3*SizeOf(Integer));
    FSortedList3:=nil;
  end;
end;

procedure Insert3(const _Value, _InsertPos: integer);
begin
 if FCount3 = FCapacity3
    then ResizeArr3(FSortedList3, FCapacity3 + 100000);
 Move(FSortedList3^[_InsertPos], FSortedList3^[_InsertPos+1], SizeOf(Integer) * (FCount3 - _InsertPos));
 FSortedList3^[_InsertPos] := _Value;
 Inc(FCount3);
end;
```

**Speed gain from step C) None!**

Conslusion: **FastMove or Algorithm change, "physical" limit of memory moving speed is reached!**

I'm using Delphi XE3 and in System.pas, line 5307:

```
(* ***** BEGIN LICENSE BLOCK *****
 *
 * The assembly function Move is licensed under the CodeGear license terms.
 *
 * The initial developer of the original code is Fastcode
 *
 * Portions created by the initial developer are Copyright (C) 2002-2004
 * the initial developer. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 * Contributor(s): John O'Harrow
 *
 * ***** END LICENSE BLOCK ***** *)

procedure Move(const Source; var Dest; Count: NativeInt);
```

So actually in Delphi are allready some Fastcode routines, but including those downloaded directly from their site (or from link i included above) made the biggest diferrence, almost 50% (strange).

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I don't understand, where the speed improvement in "Improvement A" comes from. What I intended to do with the OldList variable, was prevent copying of the whole existing content in the SetLength call (which, as you say, preserves existing content). So I allocated a new array and copied only that part of the old array from 0 to InsertPos, then moved the part after InsertPos to the new array. This should have prevented approximately half the array content to be copied twice.

Comment: @dummzeuch Where a lot of same operations are involved, 500.000 or even milions, every function call counts. Speed improvement in A is, because of: 1. removed local variable, no stack is needed; <=3 function parameters are passed in CPU registers in Delphi, 2. removed assignment to local variable, 3. removed deallocation of memory with nil, 4. removed allocation with setlength, 5. removed CopyMemory call (yes even if you call function that does nothing takes precious time ;) Only one SetLength is needed, which realocates memory, copies data and frees old data and is optimized for what it does.

Comment: @dummzeuch (character limit) In your original procedure you Allocated new memory with SetLength `SetLength(FSortedList, FCount + 100);` SetLength also zeroes all memory so it is Totaly redundant to free memory, allocate memory, clear memory and copy over cleared memory. If you call just SetLength, it allocates new memory and copies current contents, but zeroes only the remaining of array (and even this zeroing is redundant), so it's just a two step procedure, almost without redundancy ;)

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, apart from some marginally improvements due to no stack allocation, assignment to a variable (which probably was a CPU register anyway) and a call to CopyMemory that does nothing in the particular case of inserting at position 0, the speed improvement basically comes through preventing SetLength unnecessarily setting all memory to 0. So I got a speed penalty for using Array of Integer rather than ^array[0...largenumber] of integer and allocating the memory myself. Is that correct?

Comment: @dummzeuch More or less yes ... ;) With pointers in program you can do a lot faster code, but it's more work with maintaining and you loose source readability, plus you must free anything allocated, with arrays you don't need to. However, I was answering your question, and you defined an array of integers. With pointers this would be even faster because some more redundant things could be removed; a comment on CPU registers, Delphi optimizes function calls by placing up to three parameters directly to registers (if possible: pointers, int8-int32 on 32bit cpu, ...), local variables never.

Comment: @dummzeuch I tested with pointers. No speed gain from last optimized version. Can't be further improved with array, the only solution is to use other type of container or dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Not to be a spoilsport, but the solution is already in the edit to my question:

After switching from an array to [TurboPower's StColl](http://sourceforge.net/p/tpsystools/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/source/StColl.pas) the performance no longer degrades with large arrays and is quite fast to boot. The run time is down from 2 hours to less than 1/2 hour. The change was really simple. I wish I had remembered that library much earlier.

I needed the following files from the SourceForge repository (I didn't want to download the whole library):

- StBase.pas
- StColl.pas
- StConst.pas
- StList.pas
- StDefine.inc

Actually I am surprised that there weren't more interdependencies. The TurboPower guys definitely knew their trade. I wonder what they are doing today, still programming gambling machines for casinos?

Comment: If sparse array is the answer then the question is wrong. Sparse array and array are quite different. If you have a sparse array then you allocate the entire array up front and never do moves. In modern Delphi you'd use `TDictionary<K,V>`.

Comment: OK, you are right, what I needed was an array like data structure for integers that allows me to efficiently insert new entries at any random position. TStCollection provides this. I don't need the possibility of TStCollection to have unused gaps for this application.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That comment (TDictionary<K,V> used as sparse array for performance boost) is knowledgeable !